# Is there a way to change property names through reflection in C#?

Tags: c#, reflection

I am using a system where field names need to be prefixed with a given namespace dynamically.

Is there any way I can do something which can achieve something like this -

```
var properties = item.GetType().GetProperties();
foreach (var pi in properties)
{
    pi.Name = Settings.Default.NameSpace + "_" + pi.Name;
}
```

Comment: No, because it's a compiled language. You'd have to use IL weaving.

Comment: Nope, not without modifying the IL, and even then you are playing with fire since other code may reference the property. Why are you wanting to change it? May be an X-Y problem...

Comment: I am curious as to why you'd want to do this.  Do you have multiple classes with the same names across multiple namespaces and you're wanting to specify namespace to avoid conflicts?

Comment: You may think of using a dictionary, what is the scenario here, why do you need exactly something like this?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this is an X-Y problem, but I want to answer it anyway.

**No you cannot.** Why? Let's see what will happen if we *can*. We have a Class:

```
public class Something {
    public static object MyProp {get; set;} //I use a static property here just for convenience
}
```

And now you use some mysterious reflection methods to change the property to `IChangedIt`.

```
Something.MyProp = 5;
MysteriousReflectionMethod ();
Something.MyProp = 10;
```

Will this code compile? No one knows. After the method, does `MyProp` even exists? I mean the compiler knows that in `Something`, there is a `MyProp`. However, after you change the name of it, there is no such property!

***It's a paradox!***

Yeah, so basically you can't...

---

Now Regarding the X-Y problem...

You might just want to have key value pairs and sometimes you want to change the key. You can use a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`. You can put key value pairs in it and you can change the key! Here is the docs:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx